# Conditional select with a twist

Tags: jquery, selection

I have this conditional select, which does what it's supposed to. [See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ky4Jv/1/). But I would like to make an exception or change to one of the items.

If you select "Other brands" in the first select box, then there's a long text in the second select box because the script takes the text from the corresponding div:

```
$selector.append("<option value='" + $(this).attr('id') + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</option>");
```

I would like there to be another (shorter) text in the second select box - but only for this item - and without changing the content of the div.

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want to change the text altogether or just show a smaller width for the select box ?

Comment: I would like to completely change the text for this one item. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do an if that says:

```
if( $(this).text() != "Content not to be displayed in select box" ){
//-- if something should be shown. change the text here --//
      }else{
             //-- if the shorter text should be shown --//
}
```

If you set $(this).text() as a variable and then inject that, if the variable is too long, you can swap out the text for something else...

Comment: By the way, is it possible to filter by the option value="other"? Because the text of the div may vary.

Comment: Yes, you can change the if statement to check what the selected value="" tag is and check it against an 'other': [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cW7k4/2/)